https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/x509#Certificate.Verify throws "x509: unhandled critical extension"
https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/x509#Certificate.Verify throws "x509: unhandled critical extension"  when one of the truststore cert(intermediate) contains the following X509 Critical Extensions.
a. X509v3 extensions:
X509v3 Policy Constraints: critical
Require Explicit Policy:0, Inhibit Policy Mapping:0
Or
b. X509v3 extensions:
X509v3 Inhibit Any Policy: critical
0
So, is there any way to allow this and make the cert chain verification successful ?
